# How to pass a return value of a function as an index of an array in bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing

This is my program "try.sh":

```
in=$*
type=(even odd)

echo -e $in " is a " ${type[is_odd $in]} " number."

is_odd()
{
    return `expr $1 % 2`
}
```

But if I execute "./try.sh" it gives me this error:

```
./try.sh: line 3: is_odd 2: syntax error in expression (error token is "2")
```

I want the return value of the function is_odd() to be passed as an index to the array named "type"

Please tell me how can I make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having `is_odd` return its result as its status-code, I think it's better to print its result:

```
is_odd()
{
    expr $1 % 2
}
```

Then you can use command-substitution (`` `...` `` or `$(...)`) to get the result:

```
echo -e $in " is an " ${type[$(is_odd $in)]} " number."
```

Though to be honest, in this specific case I'd probably just get rid of the function and use the arithmetic expression directly — and probably adjust the quoting a bit for readability:

```
echo -e "$in is an ${type[in % 2]} number."
```

(Note that double quotes `"..."` do not prevent parameter substitution `${...}`. Only single-quotes `'...'` and backslashes `\` do that. Also, hat-tip to [jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) for pointing out that array indices are automatically treated as arithmetic expressions, even without `expr` or `((...))` or whatnot.)

That said, if you really want to return `1` for "odd" and `0` for "even", then firstly, you should rename your function to `is_even` (since in Bash, `0` means "successful" or "true" and nonzero values mean "error" or "false"), and secondly, you can use a follow-on command to print its return value, and then use command-substitution. Either of these should work:

```
echo -e "$in is an ${type[$(is_even $in ; echo $?)]} number."

echo -e "$in is an ${type[$(is_even $in && echo 0 || echo 1)]} number."
```

(By the way, I've also changed `a` to `an` in all of the above examples: in English it's "an odd number", "an even number".)

Comment: @ruakah inside of the [] array index, is already in numeric context, so $(()) is not needed.

Comment: @jordanm: Woah, I was completely unaware of that. That's good to know! I'll update my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ruakh Thanks for the answer.. And actually I had "an" only in my code. I typed the question here quickly without thinking much so missed it.

Comment: @ruakh Using command substitution works fine. But is there any possible way to pass the return value of a function directly as an index of an array? Something like this `${type[is_odd $in]}`? Or is it impossible?

Comment: @Vigneshwaran: I really think it's impossible. Shell functions are just commands, and their "return values" are just exit statuses indicating "successful"/"true" or "error"/"false". The usual way for a command to return real *information* is to print it out so that command-substitution can capture it. (In theory, I could imagine some sort of concept of "arithmetic function", declared in a different way, for use in [arithmetic expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic), but there's currently no such thing.)